# Idea for limiting photo uploadby field

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

I have a form with 10 fields of photo upload. What I want to do is to limit 10 photo upload. Ususally after you upload 10 photos and after that the the 10 fields will appear again. But this time I want to make it limitable. For example, there are 10 upload fields and after you upload 5 photos, there will be only 5 fields left. If you delete a photo then 6 fields will apear there. For now, I'm using `select count(*)` to count number of rows in MySql table and I'm using :

```
if ($rownumber == 4) { 
    "show 6 fields" 
}
```

Are there any other method to do this? The method that I'm using now are so complicated and uses codeas a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why lots of code?

```
$maxuploadslots = 10;
for($i=0; $i<$maxuploadslots; $i++)
{
    if($i < $rownumber)
        continue;
    echo "<input...."; // I believe you add them this way, right?
    // that is "ADD 1 FIELD"
}
```

the for loop will run ten times, and everytime it checks against the uploaded images count if there i is smaller the rownumber it'll NOT add a new row, else it will.

Comment: Thank you very much for this :D . But I have a problem, how to $_POST the fields because the fields names will be the same. or is it like this : name="name[<?php echo $i; ?>]" . Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

For names you can concatenate a variable or you can take input for names as an array .